# SQL Combine SELECT and UPDATE (inclusive of REPLACE and SUBSTRING_INDEX)

Tags: mysql, join

Evening guys and girls!

I'm trying to combine both a SELECT and UPDATE, however the join is causing me a major headache and hoping someone can help.

My table is within wordpress post data containing other text, images etc and contain the following: About 9000 unique posts / videos(All with unique video file names)

`[video preload="none" mp4="/wp-content/Videos/20210211_001.mp4"][/video]`

I'm trying to make the string:

`[video preload="none" mp4="/wp-content/Videos/20210211_001.mp4" poster="/wp-content/Videos/20210211_001.mp4.jpg"][/video]`

I've figured out how to obtain the filename using:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content,'"][/video]',1),'[video preload="none" mp4="/wp-content/Videos/',-1) AS `filename`
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_content LIKE '%[video preload="none" mp4="/wp-content/Videos/%'
```

The UPDATE as far as I can achieve is the following:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '[video preload="none"', '[video preload="none" poster="/wp-content/Videos/(`filename`).jpg ')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%[video preload="none"%'
```

This as far as I can achieve, adds the necessary poster tag, url and .jpg append...
However joining the pair has me stumped. Or am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Many thanks in advance for any pointers and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex replacement here.  We use a capture group below to find the MP4 filename, then build the output you want.

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(
    post_content,
    '^.* mp4="(.*?)" .*$',
    '[video preload="none" mp4="$1" poster="$1.jpg"][/video]')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%[video preload="none"%';
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Tim!
I had to slightly tweak the regex as it were truncating any content before /after
But this set me on a great path... Also taught me a little regex on the way!
Thanks again! You're a star :)

 \\[.* mp4="(.*?)".*\.eo]